# ejecutar script de npm por medio del evento click de javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Hola estoy en proceso de un proyecto y necesito ejecutar un script de npm por medio del evento click de javascript. Por supuesto,el proyecto esta en Node.js.

por ejemplo: que cuando haga click en un botón específico de mi sitio, se ejecute el siguiente script de forma automática.

```
"assets": "npm run statics && npm run imagemin && npm run webp && npm run svgmin && npm run gifmin"
```

¿Abría alguna forma de lograr esto?

muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Seria muy dificil crear un modulo con esas funciones y exportarlas?

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver un botón (imagino en una página web) con ejecutar un comando de `npm`? ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo más claro de lo que pretendes lograr? Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Mauricio. Yo sé que no se suele usar ni ver lo que estoy proponiendo,que generalmente se suele digitalizar el comando en la terminal y ya,pero esta vez lo necesito de esta forma o algo parecido porque pretendo hacer un proyecto web de reducción del peso de las imágenes, y ese proceso lo lograría automáticamente si logro ejecutar ese script desde la web. Ese script es muy importante ya que trabajaría con más de 5 módulos para imágenes, incluso pasaría los formatos de las imágenes jpg a webp automáticamente. Entiendes ahora que tiene que ver una cosa con la otra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
const npm = require('npm');
npm.load(() => {
  const mivariableDinamica = process.env.MI_VARIABLE_DE_SISTEMA;
  const opcionesdelComando = mivariableDinamica? ['--flag1', '--flag2', mivariableDinamica] : [];
  npm.run('miComando', ...opcionesdelComando);
});
```

Básicamente registras node en tu script con requiere, import o lo que sea según tu forma normal de cargar cosas en tu proyecto.
registras el método que va a ejecutar tu comando y en él le pones una llamda a `npm.run`, donde le primer argumento es el nombre del comando a ejecutar y después las opciones de tu comando.

Fuente:  https://itnext.io/launching-npm-run-programmatically-with-npm-run-f2a1b8a569a6

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Rusian López por tu comentario, me es de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @JulioLópez entonces te sugiero darle click en el icono de flecha hacia arriba que está junto a esta respuesta y que dice cuando le pones le mouse encima "Esta respuesta es útil". De igual manera si esto resolviera tu problema hay un botón de palomita para ello. No dudes en dar el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por el sitio, te enseñará como funciona todo y podrás ganar una medalla por ello.

Comment: @Rusian ya lo hice pero no muestra el voto porque aún no tengo los puntos suficientes para mostrar mis votos a las respuestas.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya creía que había solucionado el tema del todo pero no es así.Mas arriba tenía la solución, pero ahora me estoy topando con un módulo de npm que no funciona bien. me sale el siguiente error.             Error: Cannot find module 'worker_threads' from '/home/freddy/projects/imageconvert/node_modules/npm/node_modules/write-file-atomic'     Alguien me puede aydar con este problema. muchas gracias.